# Java binary search tree loop returning null object reference?

Tags: java, loops, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

I've written a remove function for a binary search tree that uses a while loop to navigate to the specific node to be removed. However, it's never getting there - it just iterates an unknown number of times and then gives me a NullPointerException.

I was wondering if it was an error in my traversal logic, but it's exactly the same as in my add function, which works perfectly.

```java
void remove(Comparable newObject){
    if (!isEmpty()){
        Node curr = new Node();
    curr = root;
    boolean isFound = false;
    while (!isFound){
        if (curr.data.compareTo(newObject) == 0){
            if (curr.hasChildren()){
                Node replaceNode = new Node();
                if (curr.leftChild == null){
                    replaceNode = curr.rightChild;
                    while (replaceNode.leftChild != null){
                        replaceNode = replaceNode.leftChild;
                    }
                } else {
                    replaceNode = curr.leftChild;
                    while (replaceNode.rightChild != null) {    
                        replaceNode = replaceNode.rightChild;
                    }
                }
                replaceNode.leftChild = curr.leftChild;
                replaceNode.rightChild = curr.rightChild;
                replaceNode.parent = curr.parent;
                curr = replaceNode;
            } else {
                curr.data = null;
                curr.parent = null;
            }
            listSize--;
            isFound = true;
        } else if (curr.data.compareTo(newObject) == 1) {
            curr = curr.leftChild;
        } else {
            curr = curr.rightChild;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

The data set I'm using yields a root with a left child, and then a right child off of that. The node to be removed is the first (left) child. However, the line that's giving the NullPointerException is

```java
if (curr.data.compareTo(newObject) == 0){
```

and I'm really not sure at all what's causing this. Any and all help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't initialize the variable as a `new Node()`, you're creating new Nodes you're not gonna use. Do it more like this:

```
void remove(Comparable newObject){
    if (!isEmpty()){
        Node curr = root;
```

and then again your `replaceNode`:

```
if (curr.hasChildren()){
    Node replaceNode;
```

and I think it's not working, because in the end of the code, you rewrite `curr` to its children, but what if it doesn't have children? Then you try to compare `null` object with some object and that's why I think it throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The thing is, the way my traversal is set up, it shouldn't ever set `curr` to a null node.  It should only follow the path of the tree. My data sets are such that I will only ever input nodes that already exist. If the root has a leftChild with a leftChild, then calling remove() on that grandchild for removal should trip the loop with a compareTo value of 1 twice (since the root will be greater than the input node, and the leftChild will be greater than the input node), leaving the iterator at the grandchild node.